# Continued fraction and classification of real numbers.

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, real-numbers

I would be grateful if anyone can tell if there are any methods to classify real numbers using continued fraction. eg: Suppose $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$  is the representation of some real number $\alpha$ then

1) if $n$ is finite then it represents a rational number.

2) if $n$ is infinite then it is an irrational number.

3) if $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational then the pattern repeats indefinitely with a period of some number $t$. What we can say about the converse?

4) for 2) case  how we can distinguish between algebraic and transcendental numbers?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is all standard stuff. You're on to something. Have a look around for the continued fraction algorithm; in particular, look for a proof that it works. That'll answer most (if not all) of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

**If $n$ is finite:**

$n\in\mathbb{Q}$

This is because a finite continued fraction is the result of a finite amount of additions and divisions of integers.

**If $n$ is infinite and periodic**

$n$ is an irrational root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$

**If $n$ is infinite and non-periodic**

$n$ is not expressible as a root of a second degree or lower polynomial.

Algebraic vs transcendental do not show any differences as far as I figured out.

Transcendental numbers can show patterns, for example:

$$e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,\ldots]$$

Comment: So you are saying that converse of 3) holds?

Comment: @shzan It does.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no *presently known* "reasonably explicit" description (i.e. an $n$-term recursion formulation for some positive integer $n)$ of continued fraction expansions that can be used to characterize even just the cubic irrationalities, although a recent paper by Nadir Murru---[*On the Hermite problem for cubic irrationalities*](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/1305.3285v3)---appears to give such a description for cubic irrationalities when multidimensional continued fraction expansions are used.

I've known about this for maybe a year, but I have not yet looked into what this all means, so hopefully an expert can provide more details and correct any inaccuracies I may have made.